# javascript create a variable with array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create this data structure in Javascript:

```js
var bar_data = {
  data: [
    [sistOper[0], tot[0]],
    [sistOper[1], tot[1]],
    [sistOper[2], tot[2],
    [sistOper[3], tot[3]]
  ],
  color: '#3c8dbc'
}
```

It works correctly, but if I have an array with 20 elements this syntax is very inefficient.

I've tried this, but doesn't work:

```
var bar_data = {
  data: [[ sistOper, tot ]],
  color: '#3c8dbc'
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've formatted your code to make it clearer - I assume the missing `]` is a typo?

Comment: why not just write a real data structure _class_ instead, with a constructor that ingests `sistOper` and `tot` and build an instance of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript's hacky-looking zipping:

```
const zippedData = sistOper.map((elem, i) => [elem, tot[i]]);
```

Or, if you're already using lodash, you can use `_.zip`.

"Zipping" is the term you're looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop to construct the `data` array:

```js
var bar_data = {        
  data: [],
  color: '#3c8dbc'
}
for (var i = 0; i < sistOper.length; i++)
  bar_data.data.push([sistOper[i], tot[i]]);
```